# Unable to Solve 'list index out of range' error

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to create a function that counts the number of prime numbers for a given range and I receive a `list index out of range` error on the commented line below and cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
def count_primes(num):
    my_list = list(range(2,num+1))
    for i in my_list:
        x = my_list[i]             # This line
        y = not x 
        r = x%y if y != 0 else 0
        z = []
        if x%1 == 0 and x%x == 0 and r != 0:
            z.append(x) 
    return len(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over the list with `for i in list`, `i` variable contains items of the list and not its indexes.
Your list contains numbers [2, 3, 4,.. num]. And the max index in it is num-2. So when you try to refer to `list[num-1]` or `list[num]` you get this error.
The solution is to remove the line in bold and use `x` instead of `i` in for loop statement: `for x in list`.